# Require.js Shim for loading JQuery UI and other JQuery Packages

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am trying to load JQuery-Ui with a shim, but JQueryUi keeps timing out when I try to load it even when I know the path is correct.

```
require.config({
paths: {
    jQuery: 'libs/jquery-wrapper',
    jQueryUi: 'libs/jquery-ui-min',
    jQuerySelectmenu: 'libs/jquery.ui.selectmenu',
    Underscore: 'libs/underscore-wrapper',
    Backbone: 'libs/backbone-wrapper',
},
shim: {'Backbone': {
          //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
          //backbone.js
          deps: ['Underscore', 'jQuery'],
          //Once loaded, use the global 'Backbone' as the
          //module value.
          exports: 'Backbone'
      },
      'jQueryUi': {
          deps: ['jQuery'],
      },
      'jQuerySelectmenu': {
          deps: ['jQuery', 'jQueryUi']
      }
  }  
});

require([
    'jQuery',
    'Underscore',
    'Backbone',  
    'jQueryUi',
    'jQuerySelectmenu'  
], 
    function(App) {
        require(['order!src/app']
     ,     function (App) {
    App.initialize();
}); 
});
```

Comment: Not sure if this is still an open question or not  I haven't actually tested anything to verify, but I notice that you have an extra comma after the deps array in the jQueryUI shim. 

I'm guessing that would prevent the JavaScript from running properly.

Comment: Another thing (that does not effect the success of the loading of jquery-ui), the App variable in the outmost scope (you do not use it there) is jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I think what damee is offering stands for older version of requireJs. Just folllow this tutorial as I did: [Load jQuery UI with requireJS](http://hippieitgeek.blogspot.se/2013/07/load-jquery-ui-with-requirejs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this project https://github.com/jrburke/jqueryui-amd to translate your jqueryui to modularized version. Then you can simply use it:

```
define(['jquery', 'jqueryui/tabs'], function($){
    $('#tabs').tabs();    
});
```

With requirejs config:

```
requirejs.config({
paths: {
    'jqueryui': '/javascript-cdn/jqueryui/' //output form jqueryui-amd
}, 
shim: {
    'jquery': {
        deps: [], 
        init: function(){
            return $; 
        }
    },        
    'jqueryui': {
        deps: ['jquery'] 
    }
}
});
```

I hope this helps.