# RequireJS randomly fails loading dependencies requiring jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, requirejs, jsviews

I have been puzzling with this for ages, and had many many different `shim` setups. Most of them giving the approximate same problem. I can't even begin to write down all the permutations I tried after reading a lot of docs on this. So I am hoping that someone will just recognize this problem and know the proper way to do this.

The problem is that loading `bootstrap`, `jqueryUi`, `jsViews`, and `bridget` at the same time **sometimes** fails **when optimized using `r.js`.**

I have a setup something like this.

### This works when not optimized:

`config.js`

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl     : 'js',

    paths: {
        "jquery"            : "lib/jquery",
        "jqueryUi"          : "lib/jquery.ui",
        "domReady"          : "lib/domReady",
        "bootstrap"         : "lib/bootstrap",
        "bootbox"           : "lib/bootbox",
        "bridget"           : "lib/jquery-bridget",
        "jsViews"           : "lib/jsviews"
    },

    shim: {
        "bridget"   : {
            deps        : ['jquery']
        },
        "jqueryUi"  : {
            deps        : ['jquery']
        },
        "jsViews"   : {
            exports     : "$",
            deps        : ['jqueryUi']
        },
        "bootstrap" : {
            exports     : "$",
            deps        : ['jsViews']
        },
        "bootbox"   : {
            deps        : ['bootstrap']
        }
    }

});

require(['app', 'domReady!', 'jsViews', 'jqueryUi', 'bootbox'], function(app) {
    app.start();
});
```

`app.js`

```
define(function(require) {

    var bootbox = require('bootbox');
    var $ = require('bootstrap');
    require('bridget');
    var Masonry = require('masonry.pkgd.js');

    // ...
    // .bridget is SOMETIMES undefined
    $.bridget('masonry', Masonry);

    // ...
    // .views (jsViews) is SOMETIMES undefined
    $.views.templates.mainView.render(data);

    // ...
    // .draggable (jquery-ui) is SOMETIMES undefined
    $('#selector').draggable(options);
});
```

Now the weird thing is, after optimizing it also works, **sometimes.** When hitting **Ctrl+F5** with the developer console open, it shows that this sometimes works, and it sometimes throws one of the errors as commented in the above code in the form of `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

I also notice that there are three `jQuery` objects in the global namespace when the page is loaded successfully. When one of the errors show up, there are only two `jQuery` objects.

And I thought the whole `modules` and `shims` game was so there would be only one.

It seems to be totally random. It puzzles me that the behavior is different between optimized and unoptimized builds.

---

I think the below stuff is irrelevant to a possible solution, but here are the other parts under the hood:

The HTML that starts the app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script data-main="js/config" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

Grunt `r.js` config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    requirejs: {
        build: {
            options: {
                baseUrl     : "js/",
                mainConfigFile  : "js/config.js",
                dir     : 'release/js/',
                modules     : [{
                    name: 'js/app'
                }],
                findNestedDependencies  : true,
                optimize    : "none", // faster for testing
                done    : function(done, output) {
                    var duplicates = require('rjs-build-analysis').duplicates(output);

                    if (duplicates.length > 0) {
                        grunt.log.subhead('Duplicates found in requirejs build:');
                        grunt.log.warn(duplicates);
                        done(new Error('r.js built duplicate modules, please check the excludes option.'));
                    }

                    done();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

*edit:*

Through the magic of google, I rediscovered a similar question I asked 4 months ago with no helpful answers: [RequireJS loading jquery-ui fails after optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653138/requirejs-loading-jquery-ui-fails-after-optimization)

The difference is that my current setup only fails **sometimes,** not all of the time.

Comment: @Louis sorry my bad, I pasted the `require` in the wrong code block. It is from the config. I edited the code in the question. Also, I have added the HTML code. I thought it would be irrelevant since the app works apart from the dependencies - but only sometimes.

Comment: What is this `js/remix` file?

Comment: It is the config posted above. I've edited remix to be `config` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Nothing jumps at me. I'd say add your `r.js` build configuration. Also, the HTML could be shortened to just `<script data-main="js/config" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>`. The rest is not relevant.